# Getting FParsec to reject unmatched start end tags?

Tags: f#, fparsec

Writing my own XML parser to learn FParsec I need to test that the XML start and end tags match or have the parser fail.

In the code fragment below ...

- The parsers `xStartTag` and `xKey` return `string`s which I want to match.
- The parser `xContent_UntilCloseTag` just returns whatever is between the tags.
- `ws` skips whitespace and `str(">")` skips a '>'.
- The `PipeN.pipe10` function is an    extension of the standard FParsec primitive `pipe5` to feed the result of 10 parsers into a function.

All these parsers compile and work.

How can I get the following parser of type `Parser<XELEMENT, USER_STATE>` constructing the type `XELEMENT_CONTENT` to fail when the start and end tags do not match?

```
00 let xElement_Content : Parser<XELEMENT, USER_STATE> =
01    (PipeN.pipe10 ws xStartTag ws xContent_UntilCloseTag ws xKey ws (str ">") ws
02                  (fun stream -> getUserState stream)
03                  (fun x1 x2_startTag x3 x4_content x5 x6_closeTag x7 x8 x9 userState ->
04                    if x2_startTag.head = x6_closeTag
05                        then
06                            (userState.Deeper(x2_startTag.head), x2_startTag, x4_content)
07                        else Reply(FatalError, messageError ("in xElementContent: head tag (%s) does not match close tag (%s)", x2_startTag.head, x6_closeTag))
08                   ) |>> C_XELEMENT_CONTENT
09                  )
```

Line 07 throws the compiler error ...

`` FS0001: All branches of an 'if' expreession must return values of the same type as the first branch which here is 'USER_STATE * XHEADandATTRIBUTES_RECORD * string'. This branch returns a value of the type 'Reply<`a>'. ``

The code compiles fine if I comment out the `if-then-else` statement (lines 04, 05, and 07) leaving 06.  Types agree in that case.  I think I understand that.

**But I need to throw an error and have the parser fail when the `string`s returned from `xStartTag` and `xKey` don't agree - How?**

I don't think knowing the types is necessary for the answer; but just in case here are the various type definitions...

```
type USER_STATE =
    {
        tag : string
    depth : int
    }

type XELEMENT_CONTENT = USER_STATE * XHEADandATTRIBUTES_RECORD * string
type XELEMENT_EMPTY = XHEADandATTRIBUTES_RECORD

type XELEMENT =
    | C_XELEMENT_CONTENT of XELEMENT_CONTENT
    | C_XELEMENT_NESTED of USER_STATE * XHEADandATTRIBUTES_RECORD * (XELEMENT list)
    | C_XELEMENT_EMPTY of XELEMENT_EMPTY

type XELEMENT_NESTED = XHEADandATTRIBUTES_RECORD * (XELEMENT list)
```

I have reviewed the [FParsec documentation](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/) in detail (especially the [User's Guide on 'Parsing with User State'](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/parsing-with-user-state.html)) but    maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to maintain user state to match XML tags. Here's a very simple parser that detects mismatches correctly (but doesn't handle nested tags):

```ml
open FParsec

let parseTagOpen =
    pstring "<"
        >>. manySatisfy (fun c -> c <> '>')
        .>> pstring ">"

let parseTagClose =
    pstring "</"
        >>. manySatisfy (fun c -> c <> '>')
        .>> pstring ">"

let parseInput =
    parseTagOpen
        .>>. (manySatisfy (fun c -> c <> '<'))
        .>>. parseTagClose
        >>= (fun ((tag1, content), tag2) ->   // *** this is the important part ***
            if tag1 = tag2 then preturn (tag1, content)
            else failFatally "mismatch")

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    [
        "<moo>baa</moo>"
        "<moo>baa</oink>"
    ] |> Seq.iter (fun input ->
        let result = run parseInput input
        printfn ""
        printfn "%s" input
        printfn "%A" result)
    0
```

Comment: You are right, the user state is for tracking nesting depth which is irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: Please, what happens inside 'failFaitally'?  Inside that is the actual answer I think - thanks!

Comment: That’s a built-in parser that simply returns a fatal error. See https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.failFatally

Comment: Same error.  :-(  The return time of ```failFatally``` is Parser<'a,'b> which does not agree with the expected return type ```XELEMENT_CONTENT```.  Both branches of the ```if``` need to return the same type.

Comment: From the3 documentation "```failFatally msg``` is equivalent to ```fun stream -> Reply(FatalError, messageError msg)``` ... which is what I had originally.  I'm definitely open to more ideas!  Thank you @brianberns!

Comment: Ah, OK. If you're trying to understand why your code doesn't compile, note that the other branch of the if-statement in my code calls `preturn` rather than returning a raw tuple. This is necessary because the entire function is actually a parser itself that is invoked via bind (`>>=`), rather than `pipeN`. This allows the parser to fail gracefully when the tags don't match. On the other hand, once `pipeN` calls your 10-parameter function, there's no way to fail gracefully. You really need a bind (or use the `parse` computation expression).